# MYSQL Split Array Strings with different length

Tags: mysql

How do i get the ID'S out of these Array Strings?

E.g.:

```
a:5:{i:0;i:47464;i:1;i:47571;i:2;i:47572;i:3;i:47693;i:4;i:47694;}
a:8:{i:0;i:48584;i:1;i:49521;i:2;i:49542;i:3;i:49799;i:4;i:49967;i:5;i:50127;i:6;i:50268;i:7;i:50270;}
a:3:{i:0;i:38752;i:1;i:38753;i:2;i:38892;}
```

split the single Id's like:

```
 id     
------  
47464   
47571   
47572   
47693     
47694   
48584   
49521
...
...
```

Comment: Oh boy.. Is this data from an actual database?

Comment: Is all that data mashed together into one column?

Comment: mother of inline data... is all of that a string? in one column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one way to do it (assuming that all id's are greater than 100 and you dont have more than 100 in one row if you do just change the HAVING clause accordingly) is make a temporary table of digits that holds 1-999 and then join to that table... if you have more than 1000 in one row of id's then you have other issues to deal with.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE digits AS
SELECT
    SEQ.SeqValue
FROM
(   SELECT (HUNDREDS.SeqValue + TENS.SeqValue + ONES.SeqValue) SeqValue
    FROM(SELECT 0  SeqValue UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) ONES
    CROSS JOIN(SELECT 0 SeqValue UNION ALL SELECT 10 UNION ALL SELECT 20 UNION ALL SELECT 30 UNION ALL SELECT 40 UNION ALL SELECT 50 UNION ALL SELECT 60 UNION ALL SELECT 70 UNION ALL SELECT 80 UNION ALL SELECT 90) TENS
    CROSS JOIN(SELECT 0 SeqValue UNION ALL SELECT 100 UNION ALL SELECT 200 UNION ALL SELECT 300 UNION ALL SELECT 400 UNION ALL SELECT 500 UNION ALL SELECT 600 UNION ALL SELECT 700 UNION ALL SELECT 800 UNION ALL SELECT 900) HUNDREDS
) SEQ
```

after making the digit table use this query to clean out the random stuff

```
SELECT
  REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(huge_str, 'i:', n.digit+1), 'i:', -1), ';', ''), '}', '') cleaned_str
FROM (SELECT SUBSTRING(huge_str, 6) AS huge_str FROM mashed_shit) t
JOIN(SELECT seqvalue AS digit FROM digits) n
    ON LENGTH(REPLACE(huge_str, 'i:' , '')) <= LENGTH(huge_str)-n.digit
GROUP BY cleaned_str
HAVING cleaned_str >= 10
ORDER BY n.digit
```

Comment: @gumbleliks i already tested it and its working would have posted a demo but sqlfiddle is down right now :(